# I can't figure this crash out: [__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I am having the **[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil** crash when I test the app on my device, but not on the iOS simulator.

Here's what going on:

I am managing 5 `UITextField` on a View Controller, then I am passing the text of each UITextField to a **another View Controller** via an `NSString` using an IBAction (when I press the button, it crashes).

**TextViewController**

```
- (IBAction)choicebutton:(id)sender {

AnswerViewController *AVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AnswerViewController"];

AVC.stringFromChoice1 = self.choice1.text;
AVC.stringFromChoice2 = self.choice2.text;
AVC.stringFromChoice3 = self.choice3.text;
AVC.stringFromChoice4 = self.choice4.text;
AVC.stringFromChoice5 = self.choice5.text;


[self presentViewController:AVC animated:YES completion:nil];



}
```

Then on the **AnswerViewController**, I am creating an `NSMutableArray` and randomizing the **NSStrings** to be displayed on a `UILabel`.

**AnswerViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.choiceAnswers1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];

if(![self.stringFromChoice1 isEqualToString:@""])
{
    [self.choiceAnswers1 addObject:self.stringFromChoice1];
}
if(![self.stringFromChoice2 isEqualToString:@""])
{
    [self.choiceAnswers1 addObject:self.stringFromChoice2];
}
if(![self.stringFromChoice3 isEqualToString:@""])
{
    [self.choiceAnswers1 addObject:self.stringFromChoice3];
}
if(![self.stringFromChoice4 isEqualToString:@""])
{
    [self.choiceAnswers1 addObject:self.stringFromChoice4];
}
if(![self.stringFromChoice5 isEqualToString:@""])
{
    [self.choiceAnswers1 addObject:self.stringFromChoice5];
}

int index = arc4random() % [self.choiceAnswers1 count];
self.choiceanswer.text = self.choiceAnswers1[index];
self.choiceanswer1.text = self.choiceAnswers1[index];
}
```

I've set it up this way in case the user doesn't fill all of the UITextFields, does this have to do anything with the crash?  I can't figure this one out, please help!

Thanks!

Comment: So where is it crashing?

Comment: It crashes when I fire the IBAction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you viewDidLoad something like this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.choiceAnswers1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if(self.stringFromChoice1.length > 0)
    {
        [self.choiceAnswers1 addObject:self.stringFromChoice1];
    }
    if(self.stringFromChoice2.length > 0)
    {    
        [self.choiceAnswers1 addObject:self.stringFromChoice2];
    }
    if(self.stringFromChoice3.length > 0)
    {
        [self.choiceAnswers1 addObject:self.stringFromChoice3];
    }
    if(self.stringFromChoice4.length > 0)
    {
        [self.choiceAnswers1 addObject:self.stringFromChoice4];
    }
    if( self.stringFromChoice5.length > 0)
    {
        [self.choiceAnswers1 addObject:self.stringFromChoice5];
    }
    int index = arc4random() % [self.choiceAnswers1 count];
    self.choiceanswer.text = self.choiceAnswers1[index];
    self.choiceanswer1.text = self.choiceAnswers1[index];
}
```

Let me know it that helps.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Don’t use `compare:` against the empty string—it doesn’t catch the case where your string is `nil` and not `@“”`. Those are two distinct cases.

Instead of this:

```
if(![self.stringFromChoice1 isEqualToString:@""])
{
    [self.choiceAnswers1 addObject:self.stringFromChoice1];
}
```

use this:

```
if (self.stringFromChoice1.length)
    [self.choiceAnswers1 addObject:self.stringFromChoice1];
```

Since in C any non-0 value is true, and since sending a message to a nil object always returns 0, this catches all the cases. And is less wordy.

Less code is better code!

Comment: Only I'd leave the `{}` in there.  Seen too many cases where a "quick, simple edit" of an `if` statement hosed things up due to the lack of `{}`.

Comment: I forbid them in my apps. I understand your argument, but my counter is always that Xcode is REALLY good at indenting, and you should have it turned on, and if you commit with bad indents I’ll stab you anyhow. My new employee is being trained out of them. Extra lines and symbols, BLEH.

Comment: It's still throwing me the same crash when I test it on a device, but it works well on the simulator.

Comment: Are you sure you’ve rebuilt the simulator version? They’re different binaries. Is it crashing in the same place? Can you post the stack trace (type ‘bt’ into the debugger and copy/paste the top 15 or so lines).

Comment: It needs to be `if (self.stringFromChoice1.length)`. The `!` is the opposite of what you want.

Comment: Heh, I always do that.